# NodeJS server hangup on stream errror

Tags: javascript, node.js, http

I have a NodeJS script that I piped streams, from request -> response

```
const { createServer } = require('http')
const { Client } = require('undici')
const { pipeline, Transform, PassThrough } = require('stream')

const server = createServer((req, res) => {
  const url = new URL('http://localhost:8000/resource/testing')

  const client = new Client(url.origin)

  pipeline(
    req,
    new Transform({
      decodeStrings: false,
      transform (chunk, encoding, callback) {
        callback(new Error('test error'))
      },
    }),
    client.pipeline(
      {
        path: url.pathname + url.search,
        method: 'GET',
      },
      ({ statusCode, headers, body }) => {
        res.writeHead(statusCode)

        return pipeline(body, new PassThrough(), () => {})
      }
    ),
    err => {
      if (err) {
        console.error(err)

        res.writeHead(500, {
          'content-type': 'text/plain; charset=UTF-8'
        })
        res.write(JSON.stringify({
          status: 'failed',
          error: 'Server exception occurred while handling request'
        }))
        res.end()
      }

      client.close()
    }
  )
});

server.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, '0.0.0.0', () => {
  console.log(`Server listening at http://${server.address().address}:${server.address().port}`)
})
```

Now in this scenario am just simulating an error, because for successful it works. So the problem is, whenever I test this out with command e.g. `curl -X POST -d '{"name": "john doe"}' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' localhost:3000` The error code block is reached but the request is terminated without sending the 500 error, is there something I am missing because I have already spent alot of time on this and its just driving me crazy

P.S. As you can see, am using the [undici](https://undici.nodejs.org/) package.

Comment: Do not use pipeline because pipeline will call `res.destroy()` when `transform`  throws an error. So all requests will be terminated!

Comment: @lx1412 I removed res from the pipeline so that after `client.pipeline` it goes directly to the callback but still got the same problem, can you shed some light on why that's the case

Comment: Plz update your code.

Comment: @lx1412 code updated

Comment: figured it out, it actually calls `destroy` on `req` so the request gets dropped

Answer (score 0):

I found a work around for this and decided to put the solution that worked for me just in case someone else ever encounters the same, so I basically isolated the `req` and `res` from the pipeline

```
const { createServer } = require('http')
const { Client } = require('undici')
const { pipeline, Transform, PassThrough, Writable, Readable } = require('stream')

const server = createServer((req, res) => {
  const url = new URL('http://localhost:8000/resource/testing')

  const writable = new Writable({
    autoDestroy: false,
    write(chunk, _, callback) {
      res.write(chunk)
      callback()
    },
    final(callback) {
      res.end()
      callback()
    }
  })
  writable.on('error', err => {
    console.log('writable err', err)

    res.writeHead(500, {
      'content-type': 'text/plain; charset=UTF-8'
    })
    res.write(JSON.stringify({
      status: 'failed',
      error: 'Server exception occurred while handling request'
    }))
    res.end()
  })

  const client = new Client(url.origin)

  pipeline(
    Readable.from(req),
    new Transform({
      decodeStrings: false,
      transform (chunk, encoding, callback) {
        callback(new Error('sample error'))
      },
    }),
    client.pipeline(
      {
        path: url.pathname + url.search,
        method: 'GET',
      },
      ({ statusCode, headers, body }) => {
        res.writeHead(statusCode)

        return pipeline(body, new PassThrough(), () => {})
      }
    ),
    writable,
    err => {
      if (err) {
        console.error(err)
      }

      client.close()
    }
  )
});

server.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, '0.0.0.0', () => {
  console.log(`Server listening at http://${server.address().address}:${server.address().port}`)
})
```

So by doing this, I have complete control on the streams that I will be dealing with hence the freedom to catch individual errors.

P.S. `pipeline` destroys all streams (calls `stream.destroy`) upon encountering an error and in this case, it was calling destroy method on both req and res objects, took me sometime to figure out.